# Best way to merge user pictures and posts for display as user entries

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm building a social network for a small community. Each user can upload a picture or post a tweet and share them with other users.

Posts are stored in the tweet table

```
tweets : id , user_id , text , date
```

Pictures are in the pics table

```
pics : id , user_id , album_id , title(ie:pic.jpg) , text(description) , date
```

Now I want to show all of them as user posts in his wall. I'm not sure whats the best way to do this.

I can use normalization by adding a third table to keep track of the user entries ant their types like

```
user_entries: id , entry_type(tweet , pic ) , date
```

Now I can :

```
$entries = $db->get_entries( $user_id );
foreach ( $entries as $ent ){

   if($ent->entry_type == 'tweet' )
    $db->get_tweet($ent->id);
    // show a tweet and for each one get it's comments

   if($ent->entry_type == 'pic' )
    $db->get_pic($ent->id);
    // show a pic and for each one get it's comments

}
```

But that means a slower code and lots of database connections not to mention I have to get each entry comments and that would slow down things in the long run.

So I was hoping to find a way to get all of these with one query. I don't know, maybe using unoin between two tables or changing database design?

Comment: Fear not the capital letter nor punctuation. ;)

Comment: i feel like i've read this before ! will do ;)

Comment: Haha - happy accident :P no but [seriously... ;)](http://i.imgur.com/v9aXr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a third table, `posts` which will look like this:

```
post_id | user_id
```

Give each post/image a unique post_id, and select all the post from this new table (this is called a many-to-many relationship between users and posts). When you query the `posts` table, `JOIN` the other tables to get all the appropriate information.

Comment: thanx - but when i query the posts how would i know which table to join it with ? shouldn't be a 3rd column in the posts ?

Comment: Nope. Join both tables on `post_id`, this way if a post is an image, it will join from there, and if it's a tweet, than from there.

Comment: got it , it seems pretty good  , but i still need to know if it's a tweet or picture to generate appropriate  html so i guess i'll add the third column anyway .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very large table; why not split the pics table into smaller tables, then using the PIC_ID you can join the tables together later or just fetch what you need. I will be faster

> table_1
>
> pic_id user_id
>
> table_2
>
> pic_id album_id
>
> table_3
>
> pic_id title(ie:pic.jpg)
>
> table_4
>
> pic_id text(description)
>
> table_5
>
> pic_id date